# Test NG Abstract Base Test Class @beforeClass

Tags: java, testing, junit, automation, testng

I am trying to have a method in the testBaseClass, which all my test classes extend, run once before the entire suite is run. I am having trouble getting this to happen. my testNG file looks like this:

```
<parameter name="test-domain" value="Base.Gamma"/>
<parameter name="domain" value="gamma" />
<parameter name="realm" value="lolo" />


<test name="ComputeCorAndPfmInternalTest">
    <classes>
                    <class 
            name="com.amazon.tahoe.service.a4kservice.testcases.BaseA4kServiceTestCase"/>
        <class
            name="com.amazon.tahoe.service.a4kservice.testcases.ComputeCorAndPfmInternalTest" />

    </classes>
</test>
```

And my method in the abstract class (BaseA4KServiceTestCase) looks like this:

```
@BeforeSuite(alwaysRun=true) 
@Parameters({"domain","realm"}) 
private void initialize(String domain, String realm){ 
...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured out that the method inside the abstract class has to be public for TestNG to bale to call it.
Thanks.